# Necesito hacer un consolidado de productos en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tengo una lista con objetos de tipo diccionario como la siguiente:

```
productos = [
{'nombre': 'Jumbo maní', 'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Jet'}, 
{'nombre': 'Jumbo maní', 'cantidad': 50, 'categoria': 'Jet'}, 
{'nombre': 'Papas de pollo', 'cantidad': 15, 'categoria': 'Margarita'}, {'nombre': 'Papas de pollo', 'cantidad': 12, 'categoria': 'Margarita'}, {'nombre': 'Ducales', 'cantidad': 25, 'categoria': 'Noel'}, 
{'nombre': 'Ducales', 'cantidad': 50, 'categoria': 'Noel'},
{'nombre': 'Bombón', 'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Noel'}
]
```

Necesito tener esa misma lista pero sumando la clave `cantidad` para los productos que tengan el mismo `nombre`. De tal forma que al final obtenga una lista como la siguiente:

```
lista_nueva = [
{'nombre': 'Jumbo maní', 'cantidad': 80, 'categoria': 'Jet'}, 
{'nombre': 'Papas de pollo', 'cantidad': 27, 'categoria': 'Margarita'},{'nombre': 'Ducales', 'cantidad': 75, 'categoria': 'Noel'},
{'nombre': 'Bombón', 'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Noel'}
]
```

Es decir, que no queden elementos con nombre repetido y que sus cantidades queden sumadas.

Comment: ¿Puedes usar bibliotecas adicionales como `pandas` o debes hacerlo en "python puro"?

Comment: Como resulte más sencillo, puedo recibir tu sugerencia, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edición** Para una solución sin pandas, ir al final.

Pandas es una biblioteca diseñada para trabajar con datos tabulados, que puedan verse como series de datos organizados en columnas, y capaz de hacer gran variedad de operaciones, transformaciones, agrupamientos, etc, de esos datos.

Usando esta librería lo que pides resulta bastante sencillo. Aunque la explicación paso a paso me llevará bastante espacio, verás que al final dos líneas de código pueden hacerlo todo.

```
import pandas as pd  # Esta es la forma típica de importarlo

# Estos son tus datos de entrada
productos = [
 {'nombre': 'Jumbo maní', 'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Jet'}, 
 {'nombre': 'Jumbo maní', 'cantidad': 50, 'categoria': 'Jet'}, 
 {'nombre': 'Papas de pollo', 'cantidad': 15, 'categoria': 'Margarita'}, 
 {'nombre': 'Papas de pollo', 'cantidad': 12, 'categoria': 'Margarita'}, 
 {'nombre': 'Ducales', 'cantidad': 25, 'categoria': 'Noel'}, 
 {'nombre': 'Ducales', 'cantidad': 50, 'categoria': 'Noel'},
 {'nombre': 'Bombón', 'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Noel'}
]

# Pandas trabaja con "DataFrames", pero es capaz de crear uno a partir
# de los datos que le des, admitiendo muchos formatos, o de un archivo csv
# o descargándoselos de internet, o de otras fuentes. En este caso:
df = pd.DataFrame(productos)
```

Una vez transformados tus datos en DataFrame, podemos volcarlos, para ver cómo Pandas los ha organizado en una tabla:

```html
>>> print(df)
   cantidad  categoria          nombre
0        30        Jet      Jumbo maní
1        50        Jet      Jumbo maní
2        15  Margarita  Papas de pollo
3        12  Margarita  Papas de pollo
4        25       Noel         Ducales
5        50       Noel         Ducales
6        30       Noel          Bombón
```

Ahora podemos usar operadores de Pandas como `.groupby()` para agrupar por una columna (en este caso `"nombre"`) o por varias (por ejemplo `"nombre"` y `"categoria"`, para que no desaparezca la información de categoría). Al resultado de esa agrupación le aplicamos `.sum()` en este caso (hay más operaciones posibles).

```
>>> print(df.groupby(("nombre", "categoria")).sum())
                          cantidad
nombre         categoria          
Bombón         Noel             30
Ducales        Noel             75
Jumbo maní     Jet              80
Papas de pollo Margarita        27
```

El resultado para Pandas es una tabla en la que el índice, en vez de ser un número como antes que iba de 0 a 6, es ahora la pareja "nombre-categoria". Para cada par "nombre-categoria" la tabla tiene una fila, y en la columna "cantidad" tienes la suma que buscabas.

Si quieres transformar este resultado de nuevo en una lista de diccionarios como la que mostraste en la pregunta, entonces hay que deshacer el índice de parejas creado por pandas, mediante la operación `.reset_index()`, con lo que el multi-indice se convierte en nuevas columnas "nombre" y "categoria":

```
>>> print(df.groupby(("nombre", "categoria")).sum().reset_index())
           nombre  categoria  cantidad
0          Bombón       Noel        30
1         Ducales       Noel        75
2      Jumbo maní        Jet        80
3  Papas de pollo  Margarita        27
```

Este dataframe resultante puede volver a convertirse en lista de diccionarios mediante el método `.to_dict()`, que admite diferentes formatos de salida, siendo en este caso el formato "record" el que nos interesa:

```
>>> print(df.groupby(("nombre", "categoria")).sum().reset_index().to_dict(orient="records"))
[{'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Noel', 'nombre': 'Bombón'},
 {'cantidad': 75, 'categoria': 'Noel', 'nombre': 'Ducales'},
 {'cantidad': 80, 'categoria': 'Jet', 'nombre': 'Jumbo maní'},
 {'cantidad': 27, 'categoria': 'Margarita', 'nombre': 'Papas de pollo'}]
```

En resumen, estas son las dos líneas prometidas que lo hacen todo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(productos)
lista_nueva = df.groupby(("nombre", "categoria")).sum().reset_index().to_dict(orient="records")
```

## Sin Pandas

Con python puro también es relativamente sencillo. La idea es recorrer tu lista de entrada e ir tomando las parejas (nombre, categoria) para usarlas como claves en un diccionario, cuyos valores serán las sumas que se vayan calculando. Un `defaultdict(int)` simplifica el bucle.

```
from collections import defaultdict
acumulador = defaultdict(int)
for producto in productos:
  acumulador[(producto["nombre"], producto["categoria"])] += producto["cantidad"]
```

Una vez tenemos los resultados en `acumulador`, éste puede usarse para construir tu lista de salida, iterando por las parejas clave,valor del `acumulador` y usándolas para crear con ellas nuevos diccionarios-resultado.

```
lista_nueva = [{"nombre": nombre, "categoria": cat, "cantidad": valor }
               for (nombre, cat), valor in acumulador.items()]
```

Sale esto:

```
[{'cantidad': 80, 'categoria': 'Jet', 'nombre': 'Jumbo maní'},
 {'cantidad': 27, 'categoria': 'Margarita', 'nombre': 'Papas de pollo'},
 {'cantidad': 75, 'categoria': 'Noel', 'nombre': 'Ducales'},
 {'cantidad': 30, 'categoria': 'Noel', 'nombre': 'Bombón'}]
```

Comment: Soy nuevo en Python y no conocía los Pandas. Agradezco enormemente tu colaboración, es justo lo que necesito...

Comment: Pandas es una biblioteca muy útil y muy potente, pero tiene tantas opciones que es fácil perderse. Verás que en este mismo sitio hay muchas preguntas con la etiqueta `pandas` :-) Si hablas inglés, [este sitio](https://www.dataschool.io/easier-data-analysis-with-pandas/) tiene mucho material y vídeos muy buenos para aprenderlo

Comment: Perfecto abulafia, GRACIAS!!!